# how to pass data between threads in c++ winform?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winforms

in this program i want to capture frames of my webcam with a thread and then send the frames to another frame named MainThread and the show the webcam in a picturebox

so i want to pass the captured frame(_frame1) from capture_frame_1_Thread to MainThread.
any ideas how to do it?

Here is the code

```
    VideoCapture cap1(0);
    Mat _frame1;

    void capture_frame_1() {
    for (;;) {
        cap1 >> _frame1;

        if (waitKey(1) == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void invoke_capture_frame_1() {
    Invoke(gcnew System::Action(this, &MyForm::capture_frame_1));
}

void start_picture_Boxes() {
    for (;;) {

        mat2picture bimapconvert;
        this->pictureBox1->Image = bimapconvert.Mat2Bimap(_frame1);

        pictureBox1->Refresh();

        if (waitKey(1) == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void picture_Boxes() {
    Invoke(gcnew System::Action(this, &MyForm::start_picture_Boxes));
}



private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
ThreadStart^ ThreadMethod1 = gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MyForm::invoke_capture_frame_1);
Thread^ capture_frame_1_Thread = gcnew Thread(ThreadMethod1);

ThreadStart^ ThreadMethod3 = gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MyForm::picture_Boxes);
Thread^ MainThread = gcnew Thread(ThreadMethod3);

capture_frame_1_Thread->Start();
MainThread->Start();


}
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class named webcam, and have those methods. Then you can have some method that starts threads webcam.startThreads();.
Then you can create private variable called frame, so you can share between threads, but don't forget to use lock to eliminate race condition.
info about lock https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/lock/

I hope it helps, I used this structure when making network filter.

Comment: consider to add sample code in the answer